# Consulta sql con valores repetidos

Tags: sql

mi consulta surge al querer seleccionar todos los registros de una tabla, pero no sé como aplicar un `where` donde indique que si el valor se repite muestre solo el ultimo.

La tabla indica entradas y salidas de un expediente, por eso necesito que muestre solo el ultimo ingreso, en el caso de tener mas de un ingreso con el mismo numero.

Aclarar que un expediente puede tener una sola entrada.

Espero haber sido claro.

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo de las tablas

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! La mejor forma de contarnos es mostrándonos las sentencias de creación de las tablas, algunos datos de prueba y la salida esperada. De paso, puedes mostrar lo que ya has intentado

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Lo que estas buscando no es un where, es un group by, con una funcion de agregacion max por algun campo. Sin embargo, a tu pregunta le falta toda la informacion, incluido la base de datos que utilizas...